# Add _top to a tags inside a particular div - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, attr

I have several a tags inside several nested div tags for example

```
<div id="top_level_div">
    <div id="inner_level_div">
        <a href="http://yahoo.com>text</a>
    </div>
    <div id="inner_level_div1>
        <a href="http://yahoo.com>text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to add target attribute to all a tags inside div with id "top_level_div". In other words every "A" tag inside "top_level_div" should appear like this

```
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="_top">text</a>
```

There could many div tags inside of "top_level_div" tag and I don't have control over the way they appear.

What is the best way to achieve this??

Edit....

I tried adding the following code at the end of the page just before </body> tag but it is not working.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#xrx_bnr_hdr').find('a').attr('target', '_top');
    $('#xrx_bnr_ftr').find('a').attr('target', '_top');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

like so:

```
   $("#top_level_div a").attr("target","_top");
```

Comment: Where should I be adding this code. I have tried to add it at various places but doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

`#top_level_div a` will get you all anchor tags descendant of an element with ID = top_level_div:

```
$('#top_level_div a').attr('target', '_top');
```

- [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors)
- [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
$("#top_level_div a").attr("target","_top");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//select the root element
//then find all the `a` elements that are descendants of the root element
//then change that set of elements `target` attribute to `_top`
$('#top_level_div').find('a').attr('target', '_top');
```

Docs for `.attr()`: http://api.jquery.com/attr

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#top_level_div a").attr("target","_top")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$('#top_level_div').find('a').attr('target', '_top');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/WWLKa/)